# Zoom H2/H2n comparison, does the H2n have less preamp noise than the H2?

Tags: zoom, portable-recorder

Does anyone have both recorders?

I understand all of the differences with regards to the mic choice and usability, I was just wondering if the new preamps were noticeably quieter.

I am thinking of upgrading from my H2, hence the question.

Answer (score 1):

Rather late to the party...

I have no personal experience but, since I was just researching this subject, I'd like to share this rather nice and in-depth article I stumbled across:

http://taperssection.com/index.php?topic=148631.0

Comment: Could you add some details from the link to your answer in your own words?  If the link goes dead in the future, this answer will not have any value which is something we try to avoid.